# c math linker problems on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, linker, math.h

Some strange error appeared after I upgraded my Ubuntu from `(10.11, 11.04 i dont know)` to 11.10.

I am getting an `undefined reference to 'sqrt'` while using math.h **and linking with -lm**

I'm compiling with `gcc -Wall -Werror -g -Iinclude/ -lm lib/matrix.c src/analyse.c -o bin/analyse.o` both source-files use and include math.h.

This code compiled without problems for and I didn't change much since the upgrade but now it won't work.

Do you have any suggestions what I can do, to find the error?

I'm sorry, if this question was asked before; there are so many posts on math linker errors and I didn't find a matching one

Comment: I do have the same problem in Ubuntu 11.10. I didn't have any problem before upgrading. In my case the problem comes from following command, Do you have any comments for me? gcc -Wall -Wno-unused -MD -o mems_seektest mems_seektest.o -lm -L. -g -DASSERTS -I../src// -I../ -I../src//src -DDEBUG -lmems_internals

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The library that you are using needs to be placed after the files that use it when you are using it from the command line. So place `-lm` on after your C files on the command line.

[Reference](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html)

Comment: This is not accurate. Normally, the order does not matter when the library is shared. The problem only appears when --as-needed is either specified, or set as default.

Comment: @VladimirPrus: You are both right :-). Recent Ubuntu versions (since 11.04/Natty Narwhal) set --as-needed as default. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition

Comment: @sleske erg.. that's a mistake now? quite a number of toolchans  always put file list at the end of command (Qt for example) by design. That also creates even more issues with automake\cmake

Answer (score 17):

**SOLVED**, this is not the common missing **-lm** problem! I'm in the same situation after upgrade to (k)ubuntu 11.10!

```
$ whereis math.h
math: /usr/include/math.h

Makefile:
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=--std=c99 -g -pedantic -Wall -lm

uname:
Linux idefix 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**You really HAVE TO place the *-lm* swith after *-o foo foo.c* parameter**

```
Output:
pidi@idefix:~/projekt1$ make
gcc -o b1 b1.c --std=c99 -g -pedantic -Wall -lm
pidi@idefix:~/projekt1$
```

So swap your flags in Makefile! GUYS. This is pretty new (and serious) BUG!

Answer (score 10):

This is a problem due to the default activation of the gcc flag `--as-needed` in the linker

More information here: http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/asneeded.xml

Simple fix (worked for me at least):

Add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the linker

Comment: Slight drawback of this approach is that the Math library is always included, also if the math library is not used. So don't use if you always include a lot of libraries independent if they're used or not.

Comment: However, the linker is unable to find references when files are given in the wrong order also when linking with static libraries.  Presumably, `ld --no-as-needed`, tagging all shared libraries anyway, lets `ld.so` work out the references.

Answer (score 4):

I found the same problem after upgrading my Ubuntu to 11.10 version.
I use Netbeans for developing and solved the problem by specifying the "Mathematics" standard library as it follows:

Right click on project, click on Properties, select "Linker" on menu, click on "Libraries" and then "Add Standard Library" choosing "Mathematics".

When compiling the '-lm' option is placed after all the other options and it works. Probably this gcc version follows a specific architecture and it expects the libraries at the end of the command compiling line.

Cheers!

D.

Answer (score 2):

```
cc filename.c -lm
```

just try..........☻