# Linking Math Library in GCC 4.6.1 (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I find a problem in the linking process of my application. I did not have the same with gcc 4.5. It tries to link math library with the following command.

```
gcc -Wall -Wno-unused -MD -o mems_seektest mems_seektest.o -lm -L. -g -DASSERTS  -I../src// -I../ -I../src//src -DDEBUG -lmems_internals
```

and report following error massages:

```
undefined reference to `sqrt'
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (using gcc 4.6.2 in Linux), this code built as it with gcc 4.5?

Comment: @birryree Of course you can't, if you use things like `float test = sqrt(5);` since gcc would optimize this by calculating the result in compile time. Try using things like `float test = sqrt(a);` where a is a variable whose value can't be known until runtime.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN - I did not use constants, I know about gcc's constants folding. And as you can see he is already using the `-lm` flag, so your answer is duplicating something he's done.

Comment: @birryree Yes dude I noticed that after posting the answer, and now feeling sorry about that :-(

Answer (score 7):

recent gcc/ld uses the --as-needed linker flag as default. Practically, that means libraries have to be specified in the reverse order of dependencies on the command line. If the mems_internals library needs the sqrt function your -lm after -lmems_internals.

```
gcc -Wall -Wno-unused -MD -o mems_seektest mems_seektest.o  -L. -g -DASSERTS  -I../src// -I../ -I../src//src -DDEBUG -lmems_internals -lm
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem with gcc 4.6.1, even with only one library.  This doesn't work:

```
$ gcc -lm eg.o -o eg
eg.o: In function `foo':
/home/nick/tmp/eg.c:5: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But this does:

```
$ gcc eg.o -o eg -lm
```

I hit this because I was using "LDFLAGS=-lm" in my Makefile.  Works fine if you use "LDLIBS=-lm" instead.

Comment: -lm be placed after eg.o ($^) is always better.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tell us what `-lmems_internals` is, but maybe the unresolved symbol comes from there. The order of the `-l` options is generally important to the linker, you should always put system libraries last.

You can check where the unresolved symbol comes from by using something like

```
nm yourLibrary | grep sqrt
```

if there is a `U` in front of `sqrt` the symbol is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the linker is using the wrong libm.