# program links properly on school machine, but not on personal one: undefined reference to log

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I can ssh to my schools Ubuntu 11.04 server where I have to submit my code and this links fine:

```
ME@SCHOOL:~/309/project2$ make
gcc -lm treesort.c -o treesort
ME@SCHOOL:~/309/project2$
```

My local machine is running Ubuntu 12.04 and here is the compiler output for the same code, but using the NetBeans makefile:

```
gcc -lm    -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/treesort build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/sortFns.o build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/treesort.o  
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/treesort.o: In function `processargs':
treesort.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using the command line on my local machine with the same code and makefile from the first example:

```
ME@MYCOMPUTER:~/Documents/CSCI/309/project2$ make
gcc -lm treesort.c -o treesort
/tmp/ccY5GqF1.o: In function `processargs':
treesort.c:(.text+0x2b5): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
ME@MYCOMPUTER:~/Documents/CSCI/309/project2$
```

This is really quite irritating, and I can't figure out why it works on the server and not on my local machine. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207464/linking-math-library-in-gcc-4-6-1-ubuntu-11-10), but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't help. `-lm` needs to be at the end of the `gcc` line, or at least _after_ `treesort.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `-lm` at the end of the link line. The order of sources,objects and (archive) libraries on the link line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html), and yours is *wrong*.

If putting `-lm` at the end of the link line doesn't help, you have some *bogus* library called `libm.{a,so}` somewhere on your system, and you should figure out where it came from, and get rid of it.

You cam find out which `libm` your linker is finding with `gcc -Wl,-t ...`

Comment: Thanks to you both. I missed it in the thread, and am a total n00b to programming in a Linux environment. Sadly too used to VisualStudio doing it all for me.