# How do I link to FreeImage?

Tags: c, freeimage

I am using Kubuntu 14.04, and installed the FreeImage library with

```
sudo apt-get install libfreeimage-dev
```

As far as I can tell, it is correctly installed, with `FreeImage.h` in `/usr/include` and `libfreeimage.a` in `/usr/lib`. However, this trivial C program

```
#include <FreeImage.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  FreeImage_Initialise(FALSE);
  FreeImage_DeInitialise();
  return 0;

}
```

fails to compile. Running

```
gcc -lfreeimage fitest.c -o fitest
```

outputs

```
/tmp/ccFbb0HQ.o: In function `main':
fitest.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `FreeImage_Initialise'
fitest.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `FreeImage_DeInitialise'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check capitalization.

Comment: That's a bit odd, because when I copy-paste your code exactly and compile it with the same command, with `libfreeimage-dev` installed, it compiles perfectly well.

Comment: You mention `libfreeimage.a` instead of `libfreeimage.so`, which you would normally actually be linking against. Is there a reason for this? Are you somehow explicitly attempting to link your program statically or something (and why doesn't that show in your compile command, in that case)? *Is* `libfreeimage.so` properly installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wouldn't normally be the case with shared libraries but only static ones, but I'm going to give it a shot anyway since it matches your symptoms, and you also mention `libfreeimage.a` instead of `libfreeimage.so`, indicating that you're trying to use the static library.

When linking against static libraries, you need to give the library arguments *after* the explcit source/object arguments to the compiler, because the compiler will only process yet unresolved symbols from the library:

```
gcc -o fitest fitest.c -lfreeimage
```

If you give a static library argument before any source/object arguments, then, no symbols will yet be unresolved, nothing will be picked from the library, and the symbols will instead be seen as unresolved at the end.

Comment: Ah, searching around a bit confirmed why it was working for me (on Debian( but not for you (on Ubuntu). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826448/linking-libraries-with-gcc-order-of-arguments) holds the secret.