# Why do I get "DSO missing" error even when the linker can locate the library?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

I am compiling a program against a shared library I have written.  This library in turn relies on `Boost::program_options` (among other libraries).  When I compile my program, I need of course to mention my library, but I get a DSO error:

```
g++ ism_create_conf.cc -o ism_create_conf -lglsim_ol -lglsim -lhdf5 -lgsl

/usr/bin/ld.real: /tmp/cc9mBWmM.o: undefined reference to symbol_ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEPSsi'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.55.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that the error goes away if I add `-lboost_program_options`.  What I don't understand is

1. Why do I have to do this even if my program does not call Boost directly (only through my glsim library).
2. Why does the linker want `-lboost_program_options` when it actually found the correct library (and location) by itself (see the second line of the error message).

The situation is similar to what was asked e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934), but I am asking something different: I know the solution is to mention the library in the command line, I want to know *why* I have to do this *even if the linker already knows* where the library is.  There is obviously something I do not understand about how shared libraries work, it seems to me that when I use other shared libraries, these libraries can automatically call other shared libraries *they* need.  However, the shared library I built does not have this ability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line)

Comment: @perror Thanks, but my question is not exactly the same, see edit.

Comment: what if you add `-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined` at the end of call of `g++`?

Answer (score 2):

Modern distros (e.g. [Ubuntu Natty and later](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/031991.html)) enable [--as-needed](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/gnu-ld-as-needed.html) flag by default in their toolchains. One of side-effects is that linker tracks order of libraries more strictly (not sure why this was done, probly to match static libraries case).