# Compiler says pow is undefined even when I'm linking with -lm, but compiles when

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, math.h

```
value *= pow(10, 3); // this one compiles
value *= pow(10, aVar); // this one produces this error:
                         //Number.c:(.text+0x469): undefined reference to `pow'
```

aVar is an int variable.

What could it be?

I'm using a makefile.
I'm excecuting "make lexanc"
My makefile looks like this:

```
lexanc:  lexandr.o lexanc.o scanner.o printtoken.o token.h lexan.h Number.o
    cc -o lexanc -lm lexandr.o lexanc.o scanner.o printtoken.o Number.o
...
Number.o: Number.c Number.h lexan.h
    cc -c Number.c

lexanc.o: lexanc.c token.h lexan.h Number.h
    cc -c lexanc.c
...
```

My cc version is:
laygr@xxx$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Please supply a minimal code example that shows this behaviour. It's also useful with information about compiler and OS together with the way you compile the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libraries should come after all the objects in the compiling option. Change it to:

```
lexanc:  lexandr.o lexanc.o scanner.o printtoken.o token.h lexan.h Number.o
    cc -o lexanc lexandr.o lexanc.o scanner.o printtoken.o Number.o -lm
```

Note `-lm` has been moved to the end.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Are you including `math.h`?  Try adding `-Wall -ansi -pedantic` as command line arguments to the C compiler.  There is usually a definition of `CFLAGS` somewhere for this purpose.</strike>

**EDIT**
This is actually a common problem that I had completely forgotten about.  Move the `-lm` to the end of the parameter list.  More specifically, it needs to be **after** all of the objects.  Take a look at [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824439/c-math-linker-problems-on-ubuntu-11-10) for more details.

Comment: At compiling or at linking?

Comment: Compiling.  Hopefully the additional verbosity will provide some insight into what is going on.  More code might help too.

Comment: I got this error in addition:
Number.c:104:9: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]

Comment: line 104 is just: int i = 0; Is inside and if, that matters?

Comment: In C90 (unlike C++ and C99), all declarations must be before all statements within the nearest enclosing `{ ... }` block.  The easiest way to get rid of this complaint is to add `-std=gnu99` to your compile lines (right after the `-c`).

Comment: @D.Shawley You are clearly linking if (a) you get an error that mentions an address and (b) you are using the `-l` option.

Comment: @EJP - the first comment was before I realized what the problem actually was and edited my answer