# : undefined reference to "math"

Tags: linker-errors, svm, undefined-reference

I try to build the program svm_multiclass (http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_multiclass.html)

I get following errror (undefined reference to == Nicht definierter Verweis auf)

```
gcc  -O3 -lm -Wall svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o svm_struct_learn_custom.o svm_struct_api.o svm_light/svm_hideo.o svm_light/svm_learn.o svm_light/svm_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o svm_struct/svm_struct_main.o -o svm_multiclass_learn 

svm_light/svm_common.o: In Funktion `kernel':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x2f0): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `tanh'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x395): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `exp'
svm_common.c:(.text+0x408): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `pow'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In Funktion `model_length_s':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x2424): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sqrt'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In Funktion `cholesky_matrix':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x3040): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sqrt'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In Funktion `find_indep_subset_of_matrix':
svm_common.c:(.text+0x334c): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sqrt'
svm_light/svm_common.o: In Funktion `model_length_n':
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

[c math linker problems on Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824439/c-math-linker-problems-on-ubuntu-11-10)

The make file is wrong, -lm need to be at the end of the *.o files